# iPhone app doesn't start after update

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

With the next update to my App I want to remove a Splashscreen I showed so far, but the App still seems to ask for the deleted view in the storyboard.

Each time I try to run the new version on my iPhone 3GS (iOS 6.1) when an oleder one is installed I get the following error message:

```
   2013-07-10 15:46:02.574 Substi[9590:907] Unknown class SplashscreenViewController in Interface Builder file.
   2013-07-10 15:46:03.190 Substi[9590:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x1ddd4490> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageView.'
```

The Problem is, that I removed SplashscreenViewController completely (source and storyboard) from the project.

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you have removed the class but you still have a view controller in the storyboard that is referencing it. Do a "search in project" for "SplashscreenViewController"

Comment: I already did this. The Splashscreen neighter exists in the storyboard nor elsewhere in the project.

Comment: Hmm... and this only happens when you're overwriting an old build with the current build? Does it happen if you install fresh? It could be the debug compile that isn't fully compressing the IPA?

Comment: Yeah I think it's a problem with the dubug build, too. When I install the Update with iTunes it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that there was just something wrong with the debug build, so it's no problem for the release so this error can simply be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to start with the basics, but did you try cleaning (Product > Clean) then rebuilding.

Comment: Yes I did. And when I delete the old version from my iPhone and run it then from Xcode it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the custom `UIViewController` custom class name in the interface builder's identity inspector. If that isn't the case, maybe there is an outlet to the `UIViewController` that is still active? Check the connections inspector for that.

Hope it helps!